# Rviz Crashes (OGRE)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running rviz I get the following error messages:

```
[ WARN] [1414015276.298139367]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL.  System Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Ogre15StringInterface17msDictionaryMutexE in DynLib::load at /home/stefania/software/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 93)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL.  System Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0/RenderSystem_GL.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4Ogre15StringInterface17msDictionaryMutexE in DynLib::load at /home/stefania/software/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 93)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

My graphics card info:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

**UPDATE 1**

Running rviz tries to compile against OGRE 1.8.1, and then gives the error messages above

```
[ INFO] [1414078694.030851551]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
```

and on this path

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I have three versions of OGRE

```
OGRE-1.8.0/ OGRE-1.8.1/ OGRE-1.9.0/
```

**UPDATE 2**

So I removed all versions of OGRE.

First installed `libogre-1.9-dev`. For some reason, rviz was also removed from my machine. I tried to install it again, and it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-rviz : Depends: libogre-1.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I Installed  `libogre-1.8-dev` and then installed `rviz` , but again getting the error messages above while running rviz and it crashes

**UPDATE 3**

Ok I uninstalled OGRE (and rviz automatically)

```
  sudo apt-get remove libogre-1.8.0 libogre-1.8.0-dbg libogre-1.8-dev
```

I tried to install rviz and this time didn't give any dependency error and automatically installed ogre too

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rviz
```

Just in case I also ran this command:

```
  sudo apt-get install libogre-1.8.0 libogre-1.8.0-dbg libogre-1.8-dev
```

Currently in  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` I have only these ogre folders:

```
OGRE-1.8.0/ OGRE-1.8.1/
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195684/rviz-crashes-(ogre)/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-22**:
Do you have a custom version of OGRE installed? From the library path, it looks like it's trying to use a custom version of OGRE rather than the system default.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-22**:
Not actually, it's default installation of ubuntu 14.04

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-23**:
Are you sure? `/home/stefania/software/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp` seems to suggest otherwise.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-23**:
This is interesting! `/home/Stefania` is not on my machine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Webots Software was the reason that rviz was crashing on my machine. After I uninstalled webots, rviz again is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0